# Generic way of returning on of the following: UIViewController, UINavigationController, UITabController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My app can dynamically change AppBaseController (Presented after login).
It can be on of the following:

Menu controller (Type UIViewController), UINavigationController, or UITabBarController

I'm creating this controller with a factory, and would like the factory to conform to a protocol that looks like this:

```
protocol MainRootApplication {
    func create() -> UIViewController
}
```

2 examples of Factory's that confirm: (Using AutoInject Swinject for Dependency injection)

```
class MenuControllerFactory: Factory,MainRootApplication {
    func create() -> MenuController {
        self.container.autoregister(MenuController.self, initializer: MenuController.init)
        return self.container.resolve(MenuController.self)!
    }
}

class MainTabBarControllerFactory: Factory, MainRootApplication {
    func create() -> MainTabBarController {
        self.container.autoregister(MainTabBarController.self, initializer: MainTabBarController.init)
        return self.container.resolve(MainTabBarController.self)!
    }
}
```

As you can see, this can not be accomplished because "MainTabBarController" is not of type UIViewController.

It there anyway to do this without force casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use an associated type?

```
protocol MainRootApplication {
    associatedtype ControllerType: UIViewController
    func create() -> ControllerType
}
```

And then your factories will be like:

```
class MenuControllerFactory: Factory,MainRootApplication {
    typealias ControllerType = MenuController
    func create() -> MenuController {
        self.container.autoregister(MenuController.self, initializer: MenuController.init)
        return self.container.resolve(MenuController.self)!
    }
}

class MainTabBarControllerFactory: Factory, MainRootApplication {
    typealias ControllerType = MainTabBarController
    func create() -> MainTabBarController {
        self.container.autoregister(MainTabBarController.self, initializer: MainTabBarController.init)
        return self.container.resolve(MainTabBarController.self)!
    }
}
```

Comment: @Seeper wow thanks! This is such a cool way of doing it! Will Just one last question, how is this possible? This is actually casting but without casting, why does the compiler approve of this?

Comment: @MCMatan Just look up swift associated types to learn more about how they work and why they are better than protocols with generic types.